# can I get the restaurant name , menus from particular place or city using facebook graph api

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to Facebook API . how can I get the restaurant name , menus,items,item-images and comments from particular place or city using Facebook graph API like foursquare API. please help me , thanks in advance

I got the access token from Facebook API

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Comment: Yes, I have read but I didn't under stand how to use it